# Who is the most generous user in the network?

Tags: support, bounties

From time to time, questions are [bountied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=bounties) and here on Meta it's often a select group of users who does this. They offer some of their reputation to make users and staff aware of what they think are important topics that need to be addressed (or have been addressed in an excellent way).

This question was inspired by [this chat message from user Daniil](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52286069): which users are the most generous (i.e. offer the most reputation in the form of bounties) here on Meta and in the network?

Comment: There are a lot of users offering their entire association bonus as a bounty, so they'd have an almost 100% rate. I'm not sure if that is really interesting.

Comment: The answer covers both the single-site and the network-wide case. Even then, I've seen users offering almost all their association bonuses in something akin to a rage quit.

Comment: makes sense! And I had totally missed that second query, need another coffee :)

Comment: But note that some users use bounties to white wash reputation points gained from participating in voting rings (on Stack Overflow main).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's relatively easy to write a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query which does this. First, [this nine-line query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1134857/users-offering-the-most-reputation-through-bounties) for Meta Stack Exchange alone:

[image]

And [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1133591/users-offering-the-most-reputation-through-bounties-networkwide) is a slightly more complicated cross-site query for the networkwide top 10:

[image]

Keep in mind that SEDE is refreshed once a week, on Sunday morning. Feel free to fork the queries to your own needs; there's a [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) to help you getting started.

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1055045/users-receiving-the-most-reputation-via-bounties) is a slightly related query I wrote a few months ago to determine who *received* the most reputation in the form of awarded bounties.

Comment: WHO IS THIS JORGE CASTRO PERSON

Comment: Would be cool to see the percentage of reputation they've offered. For example I would consider someone with 10k rep who offered 5k rep more generous than someone with 200k who offered 7k. But I guess that value can be misleading, because it doesn't consider the reputation at the time those bounties were offered :/.

Comment: @Pëkka one of [the earliest members](https://askubuntu.com/users/235/jorge-castro) of [ubuntu.se]. Posted a lot of bounties in the early years.