# Is there any place to see a leaderboard of top “Bountiers”?

Tags: support, bounties, top-users, scripts

I've just run [this script to find the list of top flaggers on travel.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308765/149926) which I thought was fascinating.  What I'd love to also do is work out how to get the list of the most bounties offered (either in number of bounties, or in total rep offered).

I can't find a script on meta, and wondered if someone with better data.se or js experience than me might know a way?

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/344526/users-by-total-bounty-given

Comment: There's even a way to get a network-wide view: [Who is the most generous user in the network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336791/295232) It essentially answers your question as well, but the answer you got here has a few more statistics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Here's a SEDE query to get the list of the most bounties offered

There is a script on data.stackechange.com (https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/344526/users-by-total-bounty-given):

> Returns, for each user, the total amount of reputation offered as bounty, the number of bounties offered, and current reputation, ordered by the total reputation offered.

Example output for superuser.com:

[image]